# Web cam live streaming for multiple users using html 5

Tags: html, webcam, broadcast

In my web site,  i shall stream my web cam to a page and other users accessing the same page should be able to see the same streamed video.Its like a Teacher teaching online (real time) and many students are viewing it.I want to do it using HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

you could realize this by using Microsoft's cloud platform (Azure):
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/10/getting-started-with-live-streaming-using-the-azure-management-portal/

Best regards